# OracleConnection Connection Request Timed out

Tags: c#, oracle, multithreading, odp.net, .net-core-3.1

Having an issue in a .Net Core 3.1 multi-threaded console app; **OracleConnection** will consistently throw an exception for "Connection request timed out" if the number of calls to **ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem** exceeds the number of threads set in **ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads**. The "task" is a call to a stored proc in Oracle which is returning data via a cursor. In a single thread all works fine, no issues

This is in .Net Core 3.1 using the latest nuget version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Have tried many combinations of settings in the Oracle Connection string, pool size, Connection Lifetime Connection Timeout etc. Nothing seems to help. Once the number of tasks queued exceed the number of threads the **Open** call on the connection will throw an exception.

Tracing using OracleConfiguration reveals the exception:

```
2020-09-23 21:30:51.997780 TID:6   (PRI) (ERR) (CP) PoolManager.CreateNewPR() (txnid=n/a) Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName, List`1 switchFailedInstNames)
```

Some threads are left at the following state "Searching for a idle connection":

```
2020-09-23 21:28:57.443815 TID:13  (PRI) (ENT) (CP) PoolManager.Get() MultiTenant : Searching for a idle connection, retryCountWithoutAffinity: 0
```

Code to reproduce:

```cs
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace OracleDBStoredProc
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Object lockObj = new Object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numThreads = 10;
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(numThreads, numThreads);

            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads+ 1; i++)
            {
                string myMsg = $" TASK {i} ";
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CallToDatabase, myMsg);
                Console.WriteLine(myMsg + " created.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void CallToDatabase(Object stateInfo)
        {

            OracleConfiguration.TraceOption = 1;
            OracleConfiguration.TraceFileLocation = @"C:\traces";
            OracleConfiguration.TraceLevel = 2;

            string taskName = (string)stateInfo;

            Console.WriteLine(taskName + "started");

            string constr = "User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPswd;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MyServer)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=myservice)))";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
            con.Open();

            var cmd = new OracleCommand("MY_APP.GET_MY_DATA", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

            OracleParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("refcur_ret", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
            p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OracleDataReader reader1 = ((OracleRefCursor)p1.Value).GetDataReader();

            DataTable test = new DataTable();
            test.Load(reader1);

            reader1.Close();
            reader1.Dispose();

            p1.Dispose();

            cmd.Dispose();

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();

            String msg = null;
            Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                msg = String.Format("{0} thread information\t", taskName) +
                      String.Format("   Thr ID: {0}\t\t", thread.ManagedThreadId);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is nThreads vs numThreads?

Comment: what if simply do this `Task.Run(() => DoSomething());`

Comment: Task.Run exhibits the same behaviour. OracleConnection "Connection request timed out". Believe this has something to do with ODP and running in a thread. But ODP does say it is thread-safe

Comment: Tip, if you want your message reach addressee - include the name @Brian

Comment: Once I had an issue with MySqlClient. I used dotPeek to disassemble it, I found the bug and created a wrapper class to work around this issue. You need to look inside and see what is causing it,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Using Threads instead of Tasks may help.

UPDATE: after careful investigation I found out that when you use a high number of Tasks, the ThreadPool worker threads queued by the Oracle driver become slow to start, which ends up causing a (fake) connect timeout.

A couple of solutions for this:

**Solution 1:** Increase the ThreadPool's minimum number of threads, e.g.:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);  // YMMV
```

OR

**Solution 2:** Configure your connection to use pooling and set its minimum size appropriately.

```
var ocsb = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
ocsb.DataSource = ocsb.DataSource;
ocsb.UserID = "myuser";
ocsb.Password = "secret";
ocsb.Pooling = true;
ocsb.MinPoolSize = 20; // YMMV
```

IMPORTANT: before calling any routine that creates a high number of tasks, open a single connection using that will "warm-up" the pool:

```
using(var oc = new OracleConnection(ocsb.ToString()))
{
    oc.Open();
    oc.Close();
}
```

Note: Oracle indexes the connection pools by the connect string (with the password removed), so if you want to open additional connections you must use always the same exact connect string.